# Eagle: Converting DXF circles to pads

Tags: eaglecad, library, pad, dxf

Is it possible to convert shapes from DXF file to pads in Eagle? Is it possible to convert circles to Eagle pads?

I have just arranged and positioned things using Fusion360 and now I want to convert it to proper things in Eagle.

So far I have manually edited .lbr file (converted `<circle>` to `<pad>`) but I'm looking for something more convenient.

```
Before: <circle x="-22.86" y="10.49" radius="0.45" width="0.001" layer="17"/> 
After:  <pad name="AP0 x="-22.86" y="10.49" drill="0.9"/>
```

If somebody is interested:

- Datasheet:
  https://datasheet.lcsc.com/szlcsc/CONNFLY-Elec-DS1131-S80BP_C77853.pdf
- Fusion360: https://a360.co/2SxftLv

[image: Fusion360]
[image: DXF in Eagle]

Comment: Looks like a repetitive symbol.Would be pretty easy to make an Eagle schematic symbol & board footprint for that. I've imported DXF files, but only  for board dimension information.

Answer (score 1):

Things that make what you want to do impractical: -

- A circle is just a shape with no inherent drill information associated with it
- A circle as drawn and converted to DXF is unlikely to be to scale
- The relative positions of circles may not be to scale
- Dimension information in the DXF won't be understood readily by a PCB tool
- A DXF circle carries zero information about the pad stack-up (copper layer by layer)

> I'm looking for something more convenient

Trade your thoughts of convenience for reliable accuracy and manually do this task.

Comment: Talking about accuracy...that is why I'm using Fusion360...for accuracy. Eagle/KiCAD just sucks when we are talking about doing more complex placement and object relations. Anyway... I will just edit `.lbr` with text editor.

I still believe this is way much better/accurate to keep X and Y the same and change only object type:

`Before: <circle x="-22.86" y="10.49" radius="0.45" width="0.001" layer="17"/>`

`After: <pad name="AP0 x="-22.86" y="10.49" drill="0.9"/>`

Cheers, Paweł

Comment: "Eagle/... just sucks when we are talking about doing more complex placement and object relations."  I disagree. I regularly place parts in symbols with tenths of mils accuracy. Your part, with 0.1" (2.54mm) and 0.05" (1.27mm) could be done pretty quickly with not much effort. The hardest part would be deciding how to layout the electrical schematic symbol for 80 pins. I don't see anything showing what daimeter to use for the pins, 0.043" works well for 0.025" square pins.  Do any other  holes need electrical connection? Or just a  pad aroud them to hold them to the board.

Comment: Ok, I see 0.9 for the holes. What is also helpful on the drawing is the dimensions of the shell, which you'd want to get into the board symbol to keep other parts from being placed in the same space.